# Bind MVC Gridview with active directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, gridview, active-directory

I am using MVC 4. I need to add a gridview in MVC view with four columns:name,phone,email and cell phone number.I need to bind this gridview with active directory.I am new to MVC and I am not sure where to start.
I am using c#.net and visual studio 2013.

Comment: Can you show us what have you done so far? And where exactly you are getting stuck?

Comment: I have added a gridview in view.Now, I am not sure where to add those active directory code: in model or controller?I am reasearching on using LDAP to get info from active directory. @Pratik